# MySql IF condition giving Unexpected Results

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I  have the following query which i'm cutting short for simplicity

```
SELECT 
  @WD:=WORKDAYS(
        if(completionDate='0000-00-00 00:00:00',
           CURDATE(),
           completionDate
        ),d.recievingdate
  ) AS workingDays,
  @QDays:=IFNULL(QDays,0) as Q,
  @RDDays:=IFNULL(RDDays,0) As R,
  @onhold:=IFNULL(ONHOLD,0) as OnHold,
  @TDAY:=IF((@WD-@RDDays-@QDays)<=0,1,ROUND(@WD-@RDDays-@QDays)) as TDay,
  @TDAY,
  @SLA:=slatime(
         d.department,
         p.activitytype,
         slaitemId,
         @sladays:=  (SC1+SC2+SC3+SC4+SC5+SC6+SC7+SC8+SC9)
  ) as slaTime,@SLA,
  IF(@TDAY<=@SLA,'OK','NOK') AS SLACOMPLIANCE
```

Below Are the Results

PhpMyadmin results
[image]

Mysql Workbench Results
[image]

**workbench results are the same as expected** as `TDay` are less than `SlA`

Same Query Giving Different Results, and now i'm out of my mind as `PHP` also giving the same results as `phpmyadmin`

What i'm Doing Wrong? 
NOTE: `WORKDAYS` and `slatime` are two custom functions

Comment: The problem seems to be with that blob in `@TDAY`. Not sure where that's coming from.

Comment: In First Glance i also Supposed that problem might b due to `blob` but i have some records where `SLAtime` is less than `20` shows accurate records in `phpmyadmin`